# Angular ng-model Syntax not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

First, I've been trying to replicate this excerpt from jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PQvQ2/1245/ and whenever I attempt to add in the ng-model=selection.ids[catagory.id] in my code, it throws an error that Va(...) is undefined.

This is my code `

```
<form ng-controller="formController">
<div class="form-group">
    <tr ng-repeat="table in districtArray" id="rowId-{{table.schoolId}}" class="unselected-row">    
        <td>

        <label class="table-center-align table-checkbox-label box-unchecked" for="{{table.schoolId}}">
            <input class="table-checkbox box-unchecked" type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxData.Id[table.schoolId]" id="{{table.schoolId}}">
            <span ng-click="updateSelection(table.schoolId)"></span>
        </label>

        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
</form>`
```

This is driving me nuts on why this isn't working.  The controller is placed within a template and its passed in the scope.

```
app.controller('distDashController', function($scope,$http,$timeout,$routeParams,adminDataCache) {
....
    function formController($scope){
        $scope.checkboxData.Id=$scope.table.schoolId;
        $scope.checkboxData.checked = checked;

    };
```

I simply want the stupid data inside checkboxData to look like the following:

`{
  "table.schoolId": boolean value, 
  "table.schoolId": boolean value
 }`

PLEASE, why isn't this working?!?!

Comment: Your fiddle works for me

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8e9x505d/ is it right?

Comment: It works for me too :D

Answer (score 1):

You declared your function inside another controller with different name, so it doesn't work as expected in your jsfiddle example. Please use angular controllers instead of simple function. For example [see this](https://jsfiddle.net/PQvQ2/1245/)

```
app.controller('formController', function ($scope) {
    // your code
}
```